# Make DateField Have no date to start

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a question about the datefield component in Flex 4.5.1. How can I make the widget not show a date to start if this condition exists?

```
if( this.intent.equals(FormIntent.INTENT_CREATE)  )
   dtEndDate.selectedDate = dtStartDate.selectedDate;
}
<mx:DateField  id="dtStartDate" width="100%" focusOut="dtStartDate_focusOutHandler(event)"   editable="true" />
```

Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the selectedDate property to null, that should clear out any existing value from the DafeField.

```
dtEndDate.selectedDate = null;
```